# Multilevel grouping and summing

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I'm having some issues with a grouping and summing issue. I surveyed the number (abundance) of birds (species) once or twice (visit) a year (year) at several points (point) across many sites (site). I did put birds in different distance bins. I'm not including distance but it does result in multiple observations of the same species during a sampling event.

To estimate species richness at a point for a particular visit I need to sum the abundance of birds for a survey event.

Using dpylr I used the following code:
`bird.group <-  group_by(bird.use, site, point, year, visit, species, sum.abund=sum(abundance))`

I get the following error

Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `sum.abund = sum(abundance)`.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Thanks for the help,

Jeff

Some data:

```
structure(list(site = c("BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", 
"BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater", "BethWater"), point = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), visit = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), species = c("BAWW", "CSWA", "CSWA", "COYE", "EATO", 
"EATO", "EATO", "FISP", "GRCA", "GRCA", "MODO", "OVEN", "REVI", "REVI", "PRAW", "AMRE", "ALFL", "YBCU", "BAWW", "BAWW", "CSWA", "COYE", "COYE", "EATO", "EATO"), abundance = c("2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You get this error as your abundance variable is a character. Try with converting to a numeric i.e. do `group_by(bird.use, site, point, year, visit, species, sum.abund = sum(as.numeric(abundance)))`. Also not sure about your desired result but if you want to summarise by group you probably want `bird.use %>% group_by(site, point, year, visit, species) %>% summarise(sum.abund = sum(as.numeric(abundance)))`

Comment: That worked... I found a character value in the abundance column and that resolved the issue. Thanks so much!